# Build a gdata Java program

Tags: java, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am stuck at the beginning of the development. I have a simple test program listed below. I followed http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/eclipse.html to setup Eclipse.

```
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.geo.impl.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(
          "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
          "AAA");
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `java Test` in console, I got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/youtube/YouTubeService
at Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 1 more
```

When I run in Eclipse, I got the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:118)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:100)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:555)
at Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 4 more
```

What's wrong here? How to fix this?

Comment: It seems required Jar files are missing. Make sure you have required Jars files are in project--lib folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) API which has been deprecated and is now replaced by [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for your second error (running in eclipse). For the first error you have forgotten to add the required jars to you class path (gdata-youtube-2.0.jar). use

> java -cp ...gdata-youtube-2.0.jar... your.java.Program

where ... symbolizes other required libraries.